# Matplotlib using twinx() - TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to have a multiple subplots with `twinx()` for the charts, but met with this error:
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support item assignment
The code is as following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,5,figsize=(8,8))
ax2[0,0]=ax[0,0].twinx()
```

When I try another way without the arrays:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,5,figsize=(8,8))
ax2=ax.twinx()
```

it comes out with another error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'twinx'

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create a `twinx` axis for each subplot? If so, you can do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,5, figsize=(8,8))

ax2 = np.array([a.twinx() for a in ax.ravel()]).reshape_like(ax)
```

Then `ax2` is a 2D-array with the same shape as `ax`, here `4,5`; and each element of `ax2` is a `twinx` instance of the corresponding element of `ax`.

Comment: Yes, am trying to have twinx for each subplot. 
Thank you very much! It works, I changed the last part to .reshape(ax.shape)